How can I run docker-compose kafka on my local machine?
version: '3'

services:
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  kafka-1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9095:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-1:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka-1:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-1:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9095
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /kafka/logs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 500
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 2
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./kafka_data/500:/kafka
    depends_on:
     - kafka-ui
  kafka-2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9096:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-2:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka-2:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka-2:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9096
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /kafka/logs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 501
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 2
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./kafka_data/501:/kafka
    depends_on:
     - kafka-ui

Port 8080 responds, but the list of brokers is not displayed.
The code has been tested many times and is likely to work as it was taken from educational and reliable sources.
kafka-ui_1   | 2024-11-18 18:07:26,780 WARN  [parallel-2] o.a.k.c.ClientUtils: Couldn't resolve server kafka-1:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka-1

I'm trying to run Kafka locally.
Help me figure it out. tried running different docker-compose examples, same problem, I don't understand its nature
golang-kafka_kafka-3_1 exited with code 1


UPDATE
This version of the code turned out to be working:

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 3
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9095:9094
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka1:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9095
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 500
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./kafka_data/500:/kafka
  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9096:9094
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka2:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9096
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 501
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./kafka_data/501:/kafka
  kafka3:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9097:9094
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka3:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka3:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka3:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9097
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 502
      KAFKA_offsets_topic_replication_factor: 3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./kafka_data/502:/kafka
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper



DNS resolution is failing. Replace machine names w IP addresses or fix DNS?
